# Ensuring Div is 100%

Tags: html, css

For some reason I can't get an image to span 100% width across the browser.

You can find my site [here.](http://cargocollective.com/btatest/)

My div reads:

```
    <div class="home" style="background-image: url(http://payload51.cargocollective.com/1/7/237315/3336908/HomeImage_o.jpg); 
background-attachment: fixed; height: 560px; width: 100%; opacity: 1; background-position-y: 0px; background-position-x: center; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; "> 
    </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you reduce your problem to somthing you could post in jsfiddle.com, or within your question?

Comment: Setting a div's width to 100% will only make it take up all of its parent element. Is the parent's width 100% of the browsers widht?

Comment: Have a read of http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ - it should give you what you're after. Otherwise, try an `<img>` element with `img { width: 100%; }` in your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

In your website you stretch your div to the whole page width. But the background image won't stretch unless you do:

```
background-size: 100%;
```

Comment: this makes the image stretch across, but it then pushes the text and menu below it down when I make the browser slimmer. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Background images are not resized with the size of the element containing them.  Why not use

```
<img class="home" src="http://payload51.cargocollective.com/1/7/237315/3336908/HomeImage_o.jpg" 
  style="background-attachment: fixed; width: 100%; opacity: 1; background-position-y: 0px; background-position-x: center; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; "> 
</div>
```

and remove the property

```
height: 560px;
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Add `background-size: 100% auto;`

```
<div class="home" style="background-image: url(http://payload51.cargocollective.com/1/7/237315/3336908/HomeImage_o.jpg); 
background-attachment: fixed; height: 560px; width: 100%; opacity: 1; background-position-y: 0px; background-position-x: center; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; background-size: 100% auto;"> 
    </div>
```

Comment: this creates the same issue as I have with Mathieu lmbert's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS property

```
background-size:100% 560px;
```

Which tells that your background image should expand to 100% in width but have 560px as height.

Comment: This squashes my image when I make the browser slimmer.

Comment: Just change the height parameter as you want.

Comment: adding background-size:100% auto; works to some extent, yet the text and menu no longer adapt with it. What I mean is the image moves with the browser, but the text doesn't. I've updated the site.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the idea of stretching a image to fit the browser's window. As this depends on the client's machine on how the site will appear.

So, I *will not suggest searching* for such solutions. Rather:

- Use repeating image as a background
- Fix the dimensions of the image container. The effect you are trying to create will still look pretty cool
- Detect the screen size and change the background as per the resolution.